# Calling MATLAB variables with varying names

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment

I have a set of variables in MATLAB with names `A1`, `A2`, ..., `A100`.  I also have a function that generates a random integer between 1 and 100.

If the random integer is `n`, how can I call the associated variable `An` without needing to create 100 if-statements or switch-cases?

Comment: Use an array. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure

Comment: Yes, for the simple example I posed, one would simply create `A = [A1; A2; ... A100]`.  But my question is instead how to call MATLAB variables with varying names.  As a more complicated example, the random number could instead be a random string `'str'`, which should in turn call `Astr`.

Comment: Change completely your approach, store your data in a matrix (or array) if dimensions allow, or in a cell array or finally in a struct if you want to pair your data with some meta information, e.g. with fieldnames.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments.  This was not a question of best approach (arrays are best no doubt), but a question only of whether other methods exist.  Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is bad practice to use such names. `A(1), A(2)` is much better.

I don't know how your variables are stored, but if it's possible to store them as an array, you should definitely do that.

If not, you can use [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/eval.html)

```
eval(['A', num2str(idx)])
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should work: `A_mat = arrayfun(@(x) eval(['A', num2str(x)]),1:100)` if you want to convert it to one single array.

Comment: +1 and I strongly agree that names like `A1`, `A2` should **not** be used.

Comment: I would appreciate it if someone would please tell me why the answer got a -1. If you think the answer is bad, please let me know and explain why. If you could also provide a better solution that would be great! That way I/we might learn something... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks greatly Robert, `eval(['A', num2str(idx)])` was exactly what I was looking for.